# why is the file not being created by f stream or even if it is the output is just garbage values?

Tags: c++, fstream, turbo-c++

I had to design a basic hospital management system by using Turbo C++ . everything seems to be working fine including the add record function but when i choose to view the records that were entered (through a main menu that was created using the same program) the function just starts displaying an infinite loop of random characters. moreover i can't seem to find the file that was created in C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BIN.

I think that perhaps the problem arises because the file was not created and there may be another file with the same name as of the class.

p.s. i know that i am using an ancient relic so you don't need to mention that and its my first semester so i am still not aware with all the technical stuff so would very much appreciate if you kept the language as simple as possible to help me and others like me.

```
class hospital {
  int bill,
  ref,
  age;
  char disease[30],
  name[20],
  doctor[20],
  address[50],
  sex;
  public : void getdata() {
    cout<<"ENTER THE NAME OF THE PATIENT"<<endl;
    gets(name);
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE ADDRESS OF THE PATIENT"<<endl;
    gets(address);
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE NAME OF THE DIESEASE(S) OF THE PATIENT"<<endl;
    gets(disease);
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE SEX OF THE PATIENT(f/m)"<<endl;
    cin>>sex;
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE NAME OF THE DOCTOR"<<endl;
    gets(doctor);
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE PRESCRIPTION/REFERENCE no."<<endl;
    cin>>ref;
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE AGE OF THE PATIENT"<<endl;
    cin>>age;
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER THE BILL OF THE PATIENT"<<endl;
    cin>>bill;
  }
  void display() {
    cout<<endl<<"THE DETAILS OF THE PATIENT ARE AS FOLLOWS:"<<endl;
    cout<<"AGE:"<<age<<"\tREFERENCE/PRESCRIPTION no.:"<<ref;
    cout<<"\tTHE NAME OF PATIENT:";
    puts(name);
    cout<<endl<<"\tTHE NAME OF THE DOCTOR:";
    puts(doctor);
    cout<<endl<<"\tTHE DIAGNOSED/TESTED FOR DISEASE(S) IS/ARE :"<<endl;
    puts(disease);
    cout<<endl<<"THE SEX OF THE PATIENT IS "<<sex<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"THE BILL OF THE PATIENT IS "<<bill<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"THE ADDRESS OF THE PATIENT IS: "<<endl;
    puts(address);
  }
  int retref() {
    return ref;
  }
}

;
void main() {
  clrscr();
  hospital h;
  cout<<endl<<"\n\n\t\t\tLOADING...\n\t\tPLEASE WAIT..\n";
  system("pause");
  clrscr();
  cout<<endl<<"\tWELCOME TO THE HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM"<<endl;
  displayrec();
  getch();
}
```

this is the function to view all the records that were saved

```
void displayrec()
{
  hospital h;
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("hospitalrecords.dat", ios: :binary);
  while(!fin.eof()) {
    h.display();
    if(fin.eof()) break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Check where the executable is or where your source files are.  The file is probably in one of those locations.

Comment: Your code sample won't even compile,  please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You haven't even shown us the class nor the body of the member function *display()*... Which I suspect, is the culprit...

Comment: @NathanOliver all my executables are in the BIN folder.

Comment: Okay. I wil edit my question and put all the concerned functions along with it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't read anything from the file, so `eof()` will *always* be false, leading to an infinite loop.

You need to actually *read* something in the loop, and initialize `h` with the data you read.

Comment: i appreciate your help a lot. but can you just show me an example snippet of it or and edited version on my  question. thanks

Comment: @ayushpaul No I can't do that, since I don't know what you have in your file. How did you write to the file? Just to the "opposite".

Comment: is this what you are suggesting
`while(fin.read((char*)&h,sizeof(h)))
  { h.display;
  }`

Comment: @ayushpaul Maybe, try it.

Comment: yup it did seem to work. thanks for your time and help.